# Python: how to apply a function for strings to list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function that cleans a string (ex. make the string all uppercase letters and etc).

```
def clean_string(s)
```

How do I apply this function to strings in a list and return a cleaned list?
I think this uses for loops but I just can't get around it.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are the modern way to do this:

```
new_string = [clean_string(s) for s in your_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function is for:

```
map(clean_string, your_list)
```

*Note*:In python 3.X `map` returns an iterator which is more optimized in terms of memory use, but if you want to get a list you can use `list()` function to convert the result to list, or better you can use a list comprehension

```
[clean_string(item) for item in your_list]
```

But if you are dealing with large data and you just want to loop over the result you better to use `map()` in in python 3.X or a generator expression in python 2.X.